# Asp.Net slow with IE 11

Tags: asp.net, performance, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have an Asp.Net 4.5 web application. Since we migrated to IE 11 we have the following
performance issue: Whenever I click on a button, the button stays selected for nearly
two seconds and then the request is executed. This does not happen with IE 10 or Firefox.
Is there any IE 11 specific configuration I have to consider?

I profiled the application with ants profiler, with Internet Explorer's developer tools 
and Visual Studio debugger. I did not find anything special on java script side nor on server side.
We are using DevExpress controls and a little bit of jQuery.

I know that I am very general, but we have no idea, what the problem could be.

Comment: Did you tested it on different machines?

Comment: Yes, it always the same problem.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate a bit on button. Is it a HTML `<button>` element or an `<input type=button>` or some other kind of control that is styled to look like a button? What is controlling the 'pressed' effect? Is there some Javascript involved with that? What else is happening when the button is pressed? Maybe you should show the relevant code for the button in the question. Also, is this the only performance issue? Does the rest of the site run as normal? Finally, what jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Is you application live? Please share the link if is so.

Comment: Show the markup and JQuery? Recreate it on fiddler?

Comment: ASP.NET couldn't be slow with any browser because it's server-side technology. So check your client-side code (javascript, html, css...).

Comment: This is the button I use:

    <ASPxButton
  EncodeHtml="false"
  ID="ApplyFilterButton"
  EnableViewState="False"
  runat="server"
  OnClick="ApplyButtonClick"
  Native="True"
  Width="96px"
  Height="32px"
  Font-Size="14px"
  Font-Names="Segoe UI, Segoe WP, Arial, Roboto, Sans-Serif"
  AutoPostBack="false"
  meta:resourcekey="ApplyFilterButton">
  <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) { Timer = new Date(); }" />
 </ASPxButton>

I removed all jQuery, java script. Timer is just a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After removing all java script, jquery etc, the problem did not disappear.
So we investigated more into the page itself. The reason for performance problems
was an update panel we used. Adding the workaround from

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000262

fixed the problem immediately.

Comment: Hi Stefan, glad you found the workaround. Most DevExpress ASP.NET controlS support callbacks so the Microsoft UpdatePanel is not necessary. Contact the [DevExpress support team](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=Question)  and they help you find a workaround that page that uses the Microsoft UpdatePanel.

Comment: I have tried this fix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000262. DOM elements getting cleared on panel updating. But still the application performance is slow. Microsoft fix solution is for 3.5 framework and they mentioned that it was fixed on next framework. My application is developed using 4.0 framework but still working on same issue. If i removed update panel whole application working fine and in my application javascript files are essential, so no way to remove js files. I have tried caching removal technique, session optimization. Are you having any other workaround???

Comment: We had no issues after that any more.
But finally we were moving from UpdatePanel to ASPxCallbackPanel from devexpress and got a better performance.

Comment: Link is broken - Jan 2017

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in ASP.NET per se that would be causing your issues. There has to be something wrong in the JavaScript is my guess. It could either be your code or DevExpress code. Do a memory profile, take a snapshot. Are there any memory leaks? Run the script profiler see what is hogging the CPU, etc. If I were you I would focus on your code and see if anything there is the issue because you can control it. If you cant find anything there check the DevExpress forums, etc.